# Find which event is specified for an object using Javascript Or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Can we  get the properties of HTML elements, with using there name or id, like following:

```
document.getElementById('id').value; //Javascript** 

$('#id').attr('class');  // jquery to get corresponding elements class**
```

And like these is there any way to get the specified event? In Html side I do this:

```
"<"input name='student' onclick='show()'">"
```

My need is,
 then how do we get which event is specified for input student?

Comment: Do you mean what the attribute contains, or which attributes are present ?

Comment: `"<"input name='student' onclick='show()'">"` Why did you put quotes like in your code? Is it string or what? This doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @adeneo : In a way similar to alert($('#id').attr('class')) which alerts the class , the OP wants to know the event handlers attached to the particular HTML element

Answer (score 1):

```
var attrs = $('input').get(0).attributes;
var f = Array.prototype.filter.call(attrs, isEvent); //Filter all attributes
//f now contains all attribute nodes that are events
f.forEach(function(e) { console.log(e.nodeName); });    

function isEvent(element) {
    return element.nodeName.startsWith('on');
}
```

For the following input markup, it would log onclick, onchange. Works for events that are attached inline or event attributes created with JavaScript.

```
<input name='student' onclick='show()' onchange='return true;'/>
```

Or

```
var el = $('input').get(0);
el.setAttribute('onkeyup', function() {});
getEventsFor(el).forEach(function(e) {
    console.log(e.nodeName); //onSomeEvent
    console.log(e.nodeValue); // attached handler
});

function isEvent(element) {
    return element.nodeName.startsWith('on');
}

function getEventsFor(element) {
    var attrs = element.attributes;
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(attrs, isEvent);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur3qx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get it, but you can do something like

```
var el  = document.getElementById("id"),
    arr = [];

for (var i=0, attrs=el.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
    if (attrs.item(i).nodeName.indexOf('on') === 0) {
        var o = {};
        o[attrs.item(i).nodeName] = attrs.item(i).nodeValue;
        arr.push(o);
    }
}
```

this would get all inline event handlers attached to the element and put in an array looking like :

```
[{'onclick' : 'show()'}, {'onmouseenter' : 'javascript:void(0)'}]
```

etc...

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nq3pK/)